# how to insert android contacts into sql server database using webservice asmx

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-sqlite

```
public class ContactDetails {
        private string Contact_no = string.Empty;
        private string Mobile_no = string.Empty;
        private string Contact_name = string.Empty;

        public string contact_no
        {
            get {
           return Contact_no;}
            set { Contact_no = value; }
        }

        public string mobile_no
        {
            get { return Mobile_no; }
            set { Mobile_no = value; }
        }

        public string contact_name
        {
            get { return Contact_name; }
            set { Contact_name = value; }
        }
    }


     public string contactGet( contactDetails[] arrayContact){//here how to insert array into database
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("
        insert into Contacts (contact_no,contact_name,mobile_no)   
        values(@contact_no,@contact_name,@mobile_no)", con);

        }
```

Comment: what issue are you getting when you execute the code?

Comment: i am a newbie of webservices i want to insert an array but what are the parameters for a method that takes an array as an argument